# Macro or global arrays

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have a socket that's receiving messages all the time. I want to check for specific values or codes under certain cirumstances. For example, I want to check if the first and second bytes contain specific values, but some other time I'd want to check the 3rd and 4th.

I can represent these codes as either macros or globals. My preference would be for macros. The code would look like this:

```
//This would go inside a header file
   int checker_array[8];
   #define CODE_1 (int[]) {0, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, 25, 1}
 

//This would be triggered somewhere 
   if (check) {
       for (int i = 0;i < 8;i++) {
          checker_array[i] = CODE_1[i];
       }
   }

//This would be the loop inside the receive function
   for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
      if (checker_array[i] == -1) {
          continue;  
      }
      else if (buffer[i] == checker_array[i]) {
          printf("Booyah!");
      }
   }
```

However, I'm worried about performance implications. The socket is constantly receiving messages and this check would run for every message. I would be checking for different values under different circumstances and so the global checker array would be redefined often. Therefore, I wonder if using macros over globals would slow the program down significantly.

Comment: Will you only use each of this compound literals once or multiple times? Will all these literals have same size? Would making `checker_array` a pointer to such a global array an option? Copying the values into a new array might have more impact on performance than the difference between a global array and a compound literal. (The fact that you hide that literal in a macro does not matter at all, btw)

Comment: You're right, a pointer would be more efficient, but I suppose I can't make it point to a preprocessor definition, so I'd have to use globals instead. Would you say that's the way to go?

Comment: And to answer your question, yes, I'd be reusing those globals/compound literals multiple times.

Comment: And also, yes, they'd have the same size.

Comment: That macro's replacement token sequence would like some parentheses around it.

Comment: What????????????

Comment: @Kaz Nope, I've asked it and it's cool. Any other constructive comments?

Comment: Why not test and benchmark both if you're worried?  It should be trivial to switch back and forth by redefining the macro.  My strong suspicion is that both ways will have negligible performance impact relative to the much larger overhead of receiving the message in the first place.

Comment: This is using both a macro and a global array.  What is your alternative thay you are concerned is better or worse?  Why not profile it?  If you find this is a bottleneck, you might want to try vectorizing it (pack all 8 bytes into a single word and compare all at once).

Comment: Please read the description. The issue is with how to represent the code part of the loop. I wanted to just vectorize it, but I can't because sometimes I'm only supposed to check for specific bytes, that's why I'm using -1 to skip over others.

Comment: This anonymous array in the macro `CODE_1` will commonly be placed in `.rodata`, the read-only static variables section. I don't think that the compiled code will allocate some space for it on the stack, copy the initial values, and access it. Instead, I would expect from a decent compiler to use the address of this static array and index it. So the effect is the same as if you are using a (global) variable. -- If you don't want public visibility, use local static variables. -- If you are anxious about performance, benchmark or look into the generated assembly.

Comment: Anyway, why don't you use a pointer as `checker_array`? It will save you the copying! Something like `const int *checker_array;` will make sure that you don't try to write to the arrays accidently.

Comment: @thebusybee would you expect a clever compiler to detect multiple occurances of the same literal?

Comment: What is your problem with global variables? If you use a global variable you can control that it only takes memory once. If you use compound literals again and again the compiler might not be able to detect that they are identical and allocate memory multiple times, resulting in larger amount of used read-only memory.And of course you can also wrap global array in some macros. If you are worried about performance, get rid of the copying thing.

Comment: @Gerhardh Mainly, yes. IIRC, GCC even documents this for string constants. If it does the same for arrays of other types, IDK, but it could use the same algorithm.

Comment: I never said I had a "problem" with globals, in fact the application I'm coding can't avoid them and this is C so OOP is much more difficult to implement, and actually impossible here. As stated before, the reason I'd prefer macros is that I already have other codes (representing single ints, not arrays) in the form of macros. But I like your pointer suggestion, it doesn't look as pretty because I have to define the globals in the source, but I'm still gonna go with it. If you want to post an answer, go ahead.